# Assign Attribute to @Html.DropdownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select, viewbag

I want to assign some ID attribute name to my Dropdown list which is using data from the ViewBag as,

```
ViewBag.Group = new SelectList(group, "GroupId", "Name");
```

and in the View side I have used Razor syntax for showing the Dropdown as,

```
@Html.DropDownList("Group", "New", new { id="testID" } )
```

But I am getting the error on this line. Can I just assign ID of This Razor syntax?
I know that the ID is generated with the Name "Playlist" But I am having 2 different dropdowns using same ViewBag. Because of that I have to assign different "ID" attribute value for them. How can it be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be using something like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Group",null,new{@id="testID"});
```

because the data for the DropDownList comes from the ViewBag to name `Group`

Comment: can I assign some Default value in This Like I have assigned in My question as "New"??

Comment: @RahulRJ: yes it is an `optionlabel` that you can very well set.

Comment: But how can I set it Here if I want my default value as "New"  in my Dropdown

Comment: Yes, how can I have the `dropdownlist` have an initial `blank` string at the beginning of the list?

Comment: Just set the option label as empty string or some content, it will be shown if none is selected

Answer (score 10):

Try it:

In controller

```
  ViewBag.EmployeeId = new SelectList(db.tb_employees, "id", "last_name");
```

In View

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EmployeeId,"Show All", new { @class = "form-control" })
```