# Disabled attribute for @Html.DropDownListFor not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have an HTML dropdownlist which I am using as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country,
                      new SelectList(ViewBag.StateCountries, "Value", "Text"),
                      new { id = "ddlCountry", style = "width: 100px;" }
                     )
```

This works fine until I add `disabled` attribute to it.

I added `disabled` attribute as follows but it didn't work. The control is still editable and the user can still select values from it.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country,
                      new SelectList(ViewBag.StateCountries, "Value", "Text"),
                      new { id = "ddlCountry", style = "width: 128px;",
                      disabled = "disabled" }
                     )
```

I also tried adding `@disabled = "disabled"` but it still doesn't work.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: this question may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828666/assign-attribute-to-html-dropdownlist

Comment: Your code as-is is working for me

Comment: I just tried adding `disabled="disabled"` to a working `DropFownListFor` and it worked as expected.

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries?  (eg Kendo)  that might be re-writing your drop down?  Start a new MVC project without any extras and see if it works there (it should) in which case it's most likely something else in your solution/project causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EvtTierID,
                  new SelectList(ViewBag.EventTiers, "Value", "Text"),
                  new { id = "ddlEditTier", style = "width: 128px;",
                  @disabled = "disabled" }
                 )
```

Change the disabled to @disabled, It should work.

Note that, if any control is set as disabled then when you submit the form it's value will not pass to a controller.

Comment: It *should* work without `@` - but, as OP already said, for them, it doesn't work with or without